# Sink inside a For-Loop gives the error "sink stack is full" in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working with the following data in R:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   369269 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ bkod : int  110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 ...
 $ bad  : Factor w/ 215 levels "4. Levent","500 Evler",..: 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
 $ mkod : int  359 359 359 359 359 359 359 359 359 359 ...
 $ mad  : Factor w/ 8643 levels "    Hilal Gida           ",..: 4021 4021 4021 4021 4021 4021 4021 4021 4021 4021 ...
 $ yekod: int  12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ yad  : Factor w/ 44 levels "BAKUGAN","BARBIE",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ donem: int  201101 201103 201105 201107 201109 201102 201103 201104 201106 201107 ...
 $ sayi : int  201101 201102 201103 201104 201105 201102 201103 201104 201106 201107 ...
 $ plan : num  5 3 2 7 5 0 2 2 0 2 ...
 $ sevk : int  5 6 4 7 6 3 2 5 5 2 ...
 $ iade : int  4 1 3 5 5 2 2 5 0 2 ...
 $ satis: int  1 5 1 2 1 1 0 0 5 0 ...

bkv <- unique(df$bkod)
> bkv
  [1] 110006 110007 110010 110011 110020 110022 110027 110030 110032 110036 110043 110049 110051 110054 110056 110061 110062 110067 110069 110071 110077
 [22] 110084 110092 110093 110094 110100 110101 110104 110109 110111 110113 110116 110117 110120 110133 110138 110143 110158 110160 110162 110186 110187
 [43] 110198 110202 110208 110213 110214 110216 110218 110219 110222 110224 110229 110232 110234 110235 110247 110249 110250 110252 110255 110256 110262
 [64] 110265 110266 110268 110269 110270 110274 110277 110278 110282 110285 110295 110296 110301 110306 110309 110310 110311 110313 110314 110315 110319
 [85] 110329 110346 110351 110354 110357 110359 110377 110379 110380 110386 110392 110394 110396 110397 110400 110406 110412 110413 110419 110421 110422
[106] 110423 110426 110428 110431 110439 110442 110444 110452 110455 110464 110467 110469 110470 110471 110475 110478 110480 110485 110490 110492 110498
[127] 110499 110503 110505 110506 110508 110509 110512 110514 110517 110518 110519 110523 110532 110534 110537 110540 110543 110544 110545 110546 110547
[148] 110549 110550 110551 110553 110554 110555 110556 110557 110559 110560 110562 110565 110566 110569 110570 110571 110572 110573 110575 110576 110577
[169] 110578 110579 110580 110581 110582 110583 110584 110586 110587 110588 110589 110590 110591 110594 110595 110596 110597 110598 110599 110600 110602
[190] 110603 110605 110606 110607 110608 110609 110610 110611 110612 110613 110614 110615 110616 110617 110619 110620 110621 110622 110623 110624 110625
[211] 110626 110627 110628 110629 110630
```

What I want to achieve is to make some calculations with respect to each element in `bkv` and append the results to a txt file using `sink` inside a For-Loop. So I created the following loop;

```
for (i in bkv) {
  new <- df[df$bkod==i,]
  dp <- new[new$plan!=new$sevk,]
  medy <- 100*(nrow(dp)/nrow(new))
  sink("Report.txt")
  cat(i, "için müdahale oranı: %", medy, "\n")
}
```

but it gives the following error:

> Error in sink("Report.txt") : sink stack is full

It creates Report.txt but it's an empty file. The report should have 215 lines as `bkv` has 215 elements.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make this loop work correctly and append the results to the text file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `sink` sets up a diversion of output to a file.  You only do this once, before the loop.  The output of `cat` will then get diverted into your sink file, until you cancel the sink with `sink()`.

So your code should look something like:

```
sink("Report.txt")
for (i in bkv) {
  new <- df[df$bkod==i,]
  dp <- new[new$plan!=new$sevk,]
  medy <- 100*(nrow(dp)/nrow(new))
  cat(i, "için müdahale oranı: %", medy, "\n")
}
sink()
```

---

It is possible to have a stack of `sink` files.  The maximum size of this stack will depend on how many open file handles your operating system will allow.

---

**Warning**

I used `sink` quite a bit as an R newby.  But I think it has some dangerous side effects that you should take note of.  The most important is that if your script has errors, and you rerun the script, then your `sink(filename)` will get added to the stack of sinks.

So unless you are scrupulous about your book-keeping of the `sink` stack, this can lead to all kinds of errors.

In my view it is far better to use the ability of `cat` to append to a file, e.g:

```
cat(..., file="Report.txt", append=TRUE)
```

Or, even better, write a wrapper function.  Something along the lines of:

```
catf <- function(..., file="report.txt", append=TRUE){
  cat(..., file=file, append=append)
}
```

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar I have edited the answer with some additional information about using `sink` and `cat`.