# How to avoid 'sink stack is full' error when sink() is used to capture messages in foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, cat, sink

In order to see the console messages output by a function running in a `foreach()` loop I followed the advice of [this guy](http://vikparuchuri.com/blog/monitoring-progress-inside-foreach-loop/) and added a `sink()` call like so:

```
   library(foreach)    
   library(doMC)
   cores <- detectCores()
   registerDoMC(cores)

   X <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar%{
   sink("./out/log.branchpies.txt", append=TRUE)
   cat(paste("\n","Starting iteration",i,"\n"), append=TRUE)
   myFunction(data, argument1="foo", argument2="bar")
   }
```

However, at iteration 77 I got the error 'sink stack is full'. There are [well-answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339306/sink-inside-a-for-loop-gives-the-error-sink-stack-is-full-in-r) about avoiding this error when using for-loops, but not foreach. What's the best way to write the otherwise-hidden foreach output to a file?

Comment: Are you actually running this in parallel? Why are you using `sink` *and* `cat` with a file?

Comment: I am running the same computationally-intensive function on 100 elements of a list in parallel using `foreach` because it would take forever using a `for` loop, or even `mclapply` (I've tried and it's much slower). I'm using `sink` and `cat` because the linked page recommended I do, and because it helps keep track of which iteration the `foreach` loop is up to.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. You don't show how you set up the cluster. Also, the tutorial you link to doesn't use the `file` argument of `cat`.

Comment: `mclapply` shouldn't be slower than `foreach` if you set up the cluster correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually use the file argument in `cat`—that was something I was experimenting with. I mistyped the code. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @Roland he may be running this on Windows, where `mclapply` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Hong @Roland I'm using a Mac. `mclapply` resulted in a definite speed increase relative to a `for`-loop but it was meagre compared to `foreach`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This runs without errors on my Mac:

```
library(foreach)    
library(doMC)
cores <- detectCores()
registerDoMC(cores)

X <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar%{
  sink("log.branchpies.txt", append=TRUE)
  cat(paste("\n","Starting iteration",i,"\n"))
  sink() #end diversion of output
  rnorm(i*1e4)
}
```

This is better:

```
library(foreach)    
library(doMC)
cores <- detectCores()
registerDoMC(cores)
sink("log.branchpies.txt", append=TRUE)
X <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar%{
  cat(paste("\n","Starting iteration",i,"\n"))
    rnorm(i*1e4)
}
sink() #end diversion of output
```

This works too:

```
library(foreach)    
library(doMC)
cores <- detectCores()
registerDoMC(cores)

X <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar%{
  cat(paste("\n","Starting iteration",i,"\n"), 
       file="log.branchpies.txt", append=TRUE)
  rnorm(i*1e4)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with my original code must have been that it didn't include sink() to end the diversion of output.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339360) , it is quite tricky to keep track of the sink stack. It is, therefore advised to use ability of `cat` to write to file, such as suggested in the answer above:

```
cat(..., file="log.txt", append=TRUE)
```

To save some typing you could create a wrapper function that diverts output to file every time `cat` is called:

```
catf <- function(..., file="log.txt", append=TRUE){
  cat(..., file=file, append=append)
}
```

So that at the end, when you call `foreach` you would use something like this:

```
library(foreach)    
library(doMC)
cores <- detectCores()
registerDoMC(cores)

X <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar%{
  catf(paste("\n","Starting iteration",i,"\n"))
  rnorm(i*1e4)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the abovementioned approaches worked for me: With `sink()` within the `foreach()`-loop, it did not stop to throw the *"sink stack is full"*-error. With `sink()` outside the loop, the file was created, but never updated.

To me, the easiest way of creating a log-file to keep track of a parallelised `foreach()`-loop's progress is by applying the good old `write.table()`-function.

```
    library(foreach)
    library(doParallel)

    availableClusters <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) #use all cpu-threads but one (i.e. one is reserved for the OS)
    registerDoParallel(availableClusters) #register the available cores for the parallisation

    x <- foreach (i = 1 to 100) %dopar% {
           log.text <- paste0(Sys.time(), " processing loop run ", i, "/100")
           write.table(log.text, "loop-log.txt", append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

           #your statements here
    }
```

And don't forget (as I did several times...) to use `append = TRUE` within `write.table()`.

Answer (score 0):

Call sink() with no arguments once inside the for loop to reset it to end the file writing at the end of each iteration and you will not get this error again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I suspect because each worker is breaking out of the loop beforehand, so this maybe works contingent on the loop reaching it.