# Foreach combine error, rbind all variables should have the same length... but they do [R]

Tags: r, foreach, rbind

I'm trying a super-simple `foreach` `.combine` task to read a folder of `Rds` files and `rbind` them into one:

```
all_dfs <- foreach(j = list.files(pattern = ".Rds"),
 .errorhandling = "pass",
 .combine = rbind,
 .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {eachRdsFile <- readRDS(j)}
```

And get the error:

> error calling combine function: simpleError in rbind(deparse.level,
>   ...): invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length

However if I loop through all files and ask their `length`, they're all the same (82):

```
for (j in list.files(pattern = ".Rds")) {
 eachRdsFile <- readRDS(j)
 print(length(eachRdsFile))}
```

The `foreach` error occurs on file 153 of 206. It works on 1:152. I opened & investigated file 153 and it looks fine, same as 152. I tried a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(parallel)
library(doMC)
mycores <- 8
registerDoMC(cores = mycores)
testdfs <- foreach(j = 1:206,.errorhandling = "pass",.combine = rbind,.multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
  eachdf <- data.frame(A = runif(10), B = runif(10))}
```

but it works fine. I ran the `foreach` for 1:152 then loaded file 153 and `rbound` them together and that works fine also. `Foreach` on files 153:206 works fine (206 is the last file). 55:206 works fine (152 files). 54:206 fails (153 files). So it may be that the issue is with `rbinding` >=153 files? My reprex attempt succeeded with 206 files so there's no problem with `rbinding` >=153 of ANY object, clearly.

Can anyone think of a reason why this might be happening? I'm running out of ideas. This feels like a bug? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks (again) to Florian Privé for help with the solve. The problem was related to my use of `writeLines` and `sink` (since I can't get `print` (or `progress bars`) to work in parallel no matter how hard I try):

```
writeLines(c(""), "log.txt")
all_dfs <- foreach(...){
sink("log.txt", append = TRUE)
```

When I outputted to list, it revealed that the sink stack full error was the problem:

[image: screenshot]

I finally fixed that thanks to [dmi3kno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254839/3975144), and went back to using the `.combine` approach with no errors.

Comment: Thanks Florian. This led to me finding the actual source of the error - if you'd like to post an answer for credit please do so. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `.combine` to get a list and then use `do.call("rbind", your_list)`.

It will probably be more efficient as well.