# How to export an r script file and not execute and display only the output?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to execute an R script file to a pdf or word and not have the figures, tables, output, etc. displayed, only the lines of written code.

I tried this:

```
rmarkdown::render('script.R')
```

But I need it without the output that is also generated. I am pretty new to R so I am not that familiar with all the options.

Comment: `render()` works for .Rmd files.

Comment: @vossi Is this guide you to what you want?: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/source-script.html

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera Then I have to first convert the document to an rmd right? Because I cannot run this code in my regular r script.

Comment: You may first provide a new Rmd file and write a chunk in which `source()` your R script. Then, you can knit the Rmd file. No conversion is required in this process.

Comment: I managed to do that but not I get the error: Error in sink(file, type = type, split = split) : sink stack is full

Comment: It seems like r starts producing a lot of empty data frames and then crashed but I do not know why it is doing that. @CarlosLuisRivera

Comment: I do not know either since there is no [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and there is no detailed information about the errors...

Comment: Do you have any for-loop-like iteration in your R script? If so, the error related to `sink` might happen due to such a kind of iteration. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296288/how-to-avoid-sink-stack-is-full-error-when-sink-is-used-to-capture-messages and please google more about the error.